# using the FileSystemWatcher to dynamically alter the items in a combo box

Tags: c#, wpf, events, data-binding, filesystemwatcher

OK, so I am trying to use the FileSystemWatcher to watch for changes in a directory and then dynamically change the items in a combo box.  my populateCb() method works initially when the user control is loaded.  and i added a break point inside the watcher changed event which breaks when i change the contents of the directory. so I know the events are being triggered and the watcher_Changed method is being called.  but the contents of my combo-box do not change...  What am I doing wrong?

```
public partial class HtmlViewer : UserControl
{
    private List<string> emails = new List<string>();
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher("emailTemplates", "*.msg");
    public HtmlViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        populateCb();
        watcher.Changed += watcher_Changed;
        watcher.Created += watcher_Changed;
        watcher.Deleted += watcher_Changed;
        watcher.Renamed += watcher_Changed;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    }

    void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                populateCb();
            }
            ));

    }
    private void populateCb()
    {
        emails.Clear();
        foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("emailTemplates", "*.msg", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            emails.Add(file);
        }
        emailSelector.ItemsSource = emails;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure but probably you need to set ItemSource to null as first line in the populateCb method. (Or use an ObservableCollection)

Comment: that worked! thanks!  that is so strange, why doesn't setting the item source again over-ride its previous value?  and I will have to look into ObservableCollections, that sounds like the proper solution.  anyway @Steve, you should add an answer so I can mark this question as answered.

Comment: Because you are not setting a new itemsource. It is the same object. You have changed its content but the object (a List<string>) is not capable to notify the changes. Setting ItemSource = null, and then resetting it again to the same object informs the combobox binding code of the change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to set the `ItemSource` to null before changing the `List<string> emails`

```
private void populateCb()
{
    emailSelector.ItemsSource = null;
    emails.Clear();
    foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("emailTemplates", "*.msg", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        emails.Add(file);
    }
    emailSelector.ItemsSource = emails;
}
```

Without it you are not changing the previous ItemSource. It is the same object. The `List<string>` has no capability to notify the binding infrastructure of WPF of changes to its elements. So clearing the items, readding them is totally invisible to the ComboBox. Instead setting ItemSource = null, and then resetting it again informs the combobox of the changes.

A possible (and probably better option) is to change your List to an [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) that has the capability to notifiy changes